# The Disparate Clarification (newly coined term by me)

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, terminology

I'm curious if there is actually a term for what I have just deemed "the disparate clarification" -- for example I just saw a tweet that said "Let's party, and by party I mean scramble to figure out how to go to Mexico for cheaper healthcare." I think these types of sentences (not the content here) with such irrelevance are so funny but I don't know what they're called/ if there is a term !

Comment: It's certainly using a non-sequitur. [[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/non_sequitur): noun
a conclusion or statement that does not logically follow from the previous argument or statement.]

Comment: The closest thing I'm getting right now is an adjective, irreverent.  Maybe the phrase you invented will stick.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Non-sequiturs don't have to be funny, do they?  I think this question is different.  Also, there's a double-entendre here, since sometimes people talk, in the U.S., about going to Mexico for vacation.

Comment: No they don't, but I'd argue that not all people find such sentences (and certainly not every such sentence) all that funny. Although a lot of humour is based on clever uses of incongruity.

Comment: In the context of the recent repeal of the Affordable Care Act in the US, it is the *lets party* part that is being used sardonically. I read the parenthetical as containing the actual truth of the matter, and it soberizes the sentence's mood. *soberizing parenthetical*??

Comment: I don't think this is the same as the duplicate. That question is asking about true non sequiturs—the example is a third party adding an irrelevant statement to a dialogue. This question appears to be specifically asking about the construction ***X, and by X I mean Y***.

Answer (score 1):

Great question, did some digging and found [Dissimile](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Dissimile):

> you're making a comparison between two completely unlike things that
>   don't deserve to be compared in the first place, and trying to justify
>   it by making ridiculous exceptions that make your whole point
>   completely moot.

Comment: That's not the definition I'm aware of. [[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dissimile)]: << _dissimile_
[noun]:
a comparison of two dissimilar objects for the purpose of illustration>> eg _as different as chalk and cheese_

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You're right about dictionary definitions. But this is from TV Tropes, and if you go through that linked page, you'll see that this is what OP asked for. I hope to see a real word for this, though.

Comment: @NVZ 'What OP asked for' and 'acceptable answers on ELU, with substantive endorsement from creditable authorities' don't always match.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth True, that.

Answer (score 1):

The term I would use for the phenomenon you ask about is **Humpty Dumpty glorification**, in honor of this exchange between Humpty Dumpty and Alice in *Through the Looking Glass*:

> "As I was saying, that [calculation] seems to be done right — though I haven't time to look it over thoroughly just now — and that shows that there are three hundred and sixty-four days when you might get un-birthday presents —'
>
> 'Certainly,' said Alice.
>
> 'And only one for birthday presents, you know. There's glory for you!'
>
> 'I don't know what you mean by "glory",' Alice said.
>
> Humpty Dumpty smiled contemptuously. 'Of course you don't — till I tell you. I meant "there's a nice knock-down argument for you!"'
>
> 'But "glory" doesn't mean "a nice knock-down argument",' Alice objected.
>
> 'When I use a word,' Humpty Dumpty said, in rather a scornful tone, 'it means just what I choose it to mean — neither more nor less.'
>
> 'The question is,' said Alice, 'whether you can make words mean so many different things.'
>
> 'The question is,' said Humpty Dumpty, 'which is to be master — that's all.'